# Querying by current time (postgres, psycopg2, python)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

I'm making a Flask application that queries a postgreSQL database using psycopg2. The database has a column **timestamps** in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS. I want to print ONLY the results that match the current time up to the minute (the moment I query the db). I think what I'm looking for is a dynamic query.

For example, here I want to print the number of users CURRENTLY active.

```
def userCount(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * from user_list WHERE timestamps = ?")
    print 'Users currently active: ' + str(len(cur.fetchall()))
```

I've tried placing several different things where the question mark is above, including a variable **dt** defined using python's datetime module. Nothing has worked--I either end up getting a count of all the users in the database, or an error that the column does not exist.

To reiterate, I know how to specify date-time parameters but what I need is the CURRENT date-time. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Define active. Last 5 minutes? 10?

Comment: `from datetime import datetime` then `cur.execute("SELECT * from user_list WHERE timestamps = %s", (datetime.now().replace(microsecond = 0),))`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I want the most recent data, so I think just the last 1 minute. I'd need to disregard the seconds at the end.

Comment: Truncating to minutes will return actives from 0 to 60 seconds. You need date arithmetic.

Comment: @Abelisto so this would ignore the seconds at the end, correct? For some reason no matter what variations I try, I end up getting 0 users as a result (and I know it's not correct because I am on the app myself acting as an active user)

Comment: No, it ignore microseconds. Yet another solution: `WHERE (current_timestamp - timestamps) < make_interval(secs := 30)`. Just set the desired amount of seconds.

Comment: @Abelisto I think that second solution works!!!!!!!!! I set different intervals to test it out and it seems to be displaying the correct numbers now. Thank you so much!

Comment: PS: Small but significant correction: `timestamps > (current_timestamp - make_interval(secs := 30))` - in this case it will be possible to use an index on `timestamps` column. Good luck.

Comment: @Abelisto Do you know if I could create a variable outside of the query to set the interval? So for example I can say (secs := setTime) and define that time elsewhere?

Comment: `cur.execute("SELECT * from user_list WHERE timestamps >  (current_timestamp - make_interval(secs := %s))", (yourVariable,))` http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: @Abelisto I had to put the (yourVariable) part in brackets [] since ints can't be indexed but it worked! Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 intervalInSecs = 30;

 def userCount(conn):
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * from user_list WHERE timestamps > (current_timestamp - make_interval(secs := %s))", [intervalInSecs])
        print 'Users currently active: ' + str(len(cur.fetchall()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the database date?

```
WHERE timestamps = current_date
```

Or, if the value is stored as a string:

```
WHERE timestamps = TO_CHAR(current_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Just tried current_date. No errors, but it doesn't do what I want it to. It returns a count of ALL the users in the database and isn't filtering by current date/time.

Comment: @Sarah `current_date` returns exactly current date, without time part. Use `date_trunc('secs', current_timestamp)` instead.